# Index maintenance in distributed availability group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, index-maintenance

I'd like your opinion about Index Maintenance in Distributed availability groups. In this way, the size of the databases is at the limit of terabytes, and this process is supposed to be transferred to one or more other sites. In your opinion, what best practices should we consider here?

These sites are connected synchronously; we should not lose data. Now we want to execute the Rebuild index operation. Considering the type of waits and network bandwidth, etc., what is the best way to manage indexes and perform these processes?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like your opinion about Index Maintenance

Don't do it. It's not worth the work, the performance gains will likely be minimal to none, and it'll grow out your database size. The main subsequent benefits that can come from it, such as updated statistics, are processes that can be ran directly without wasting the server's time on index rebuilds.

Additionally, having to synchronize those changes across Availability Group replicas is going to cause unnecessary contention on them as they try to catch up. Because your Availability Group is running in synchronous mode, that means it's also possible for your primary replica to be under contention while the secondaries are catching up.

Further useful reading on why it's a waste can be found in Tara Kizer's article ["Index Maintenance Madness"](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/index-maintenance-madness/), but here's some highlights:

> we also briefly discuss why rebuilding/reorganizing indexes isn’t necessary all that often

> I’ve only had a handful of clients who insisted it was necessary to avoid huge performance problems. **Without even looking at the rest of the server, I am confident the issue is Parameter Sniffing or out-of-date statistics.** When you rebuild an index, you get updated statistics for that index and any execution plan that references that index gets wiped from the plan cache. But that’s **a very expensive way to do those two tasks!** If the issue is with out-of-date statistics, then update statistics daily. If the issue is with Parameter Sniffing, then you’ve got more work to do.